# How to compare two populations

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I've collected data to judge the attitude of teachers and the students on a 20-items 5-point Likert scale towards computer. Now I want to compare their (Teachers vs Students) responses. How do I analyze my results. what type of test can I use for comparison between the two categories (Teachers and Students)? plz suggest﻿

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extent of your data collection you'll likely want to consider [Student's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) or [Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test).

Comment: I want to make my question a bit clear. I collected responses from two groups (the teachers and the students) on a same scale. My purpose is to know that which group has a tendency towards computer and to whether this tendency is statistically significant.

Comment: A "tendency" toward "computer" can only be significant to the extent that it's different from some metric. Are you testing whether the groups are different on said measure or if each group is different from some expected value?

Comment: Thanks dear. I'm interested to measure  the difference of opinion between the groups (Teachers /Students). What teachers say and what students say about a particular statement e.g. ''I think that working with computers would be enjoyable'' Options SD, D, U, A, SA

Comment: You're going to want to quantify these responses (1 - SD, 2 - D, etc.) And find run an independent samples t-test using the values from each group against the other.